# Optimizing my site for internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I am kinda new to the whole html/css thing, but i managed to make a decent page for my portfolio website, so far. The things is, that is looks like crap in Internet Explorer. I have tried to optimize it, so that my css animations work and so forth, but i can't seem to make it work properly.

www.thomasteilmann.dk

If you take a look, you'll know what i mean. It should work properly in anything but IE. 
if anyone could give me some advice on how to reach my goal, that would be great! :)

And yes, i know my code is messy :P

classes below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <head>
        <title>thomasteilmann.dk</title>    
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="header">
            <h1><img src="images/thomas_logo_Web.png" alt="Sick Logo" /></a></h1>
        </div>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="view-first">
            <img src="images/cosmic_art_icon.jpg"/>
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>Cosmic Art</h2>
                <p>A galleri of cosmic art made in Photoshop</p>
                <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="view-second">
            <img src="images/thomas_web.jpg"/>
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>About myself</h2>
                <p>Information about my skills and my personality in general</p>
                <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="view-third">
            <img src="images/web_web.jpg"/>
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>Websites</h2>
                <p>A list of websites i've made/worked on.</p>
                <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="view-fourth">
            <img src="images/ice_age_web.jpg"/>
            <div class="mask">
                <h2>Cartoon Art</h2>
                <p>A galleri of Cartoon art made in Photoshop</p>
                <a href="#" class="info">View</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
body {
    background: #21211f;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;

}

.header{
    position: absolute;
    width: 700px;
    padding-bottom:50px;
    margin-left: 23%;
    float: left;


}

h1 img{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#content{
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;

    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Georgia, times, serif;
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-left: 22%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 30px;
}


img {
    border: none;
}

/*
 * View one
*/

.view-first {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-left: 33px;
    float: left;
    border: 5px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view-first .mask, .view .content {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.view-first img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-first p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-first a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


.view-first .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(219,127,8, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.view-first a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.view-first:hover img {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);

}
.view-first:hover .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.view-first:hover h2,
.view-first:hover p,
.view-first:hover a.info {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);

}
.view-first:hover p {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.view-first:hover a.info {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

/**
 * View two
 */

.view-second {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    margin: 3px;

    margin-left: 400px;
    float: right;
    border: 5px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view-second .mask, .view .content {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.view-second img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-second h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-second p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center;

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-second a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


.view-second .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(219,127,8, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.view-second a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.view-second:hover img {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);

}
.view-second:hover .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.view-second:hover h2,
.view-second:hover p,
.view-second:hover a.info {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);

}
.view-second:hover p {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.view-second:hover a.info {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

/**
 * View three
 */

.view-third {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-left: 33px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 240px;
    border: 5px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view-third .mask, .view .content {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.view-third img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-third h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-third p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 20px;
    text-align: center;

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-third a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


.view-third .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(219,127,8, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.view-third a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.view-third:hover img {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);

}
.view-third:hover .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.view-third:hover h2,
.view-third:hover p,
.view-third:hover a.info {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);

}
.view-third:hover p {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.view-third:hover a.info {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}


/**
 * View four
 */

.view-fourth {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    margin: 3px;
    margin-top: 240px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    float: right;
    border: 5px solid white;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px #e6e6e6;
    cursor: default;
    background: #fff url(../images/bgimg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
.view-fourth .mask, .view .content {
    width: 279px;
    height: 198px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.view-fourth img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-fourth h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.view-fourth p {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px 0px;
    text-align: center;

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.view-fourth a.info {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 14px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;

    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


.view-fourth .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";

    opacity: 0;
    background-color: rgba(219,127,8, 0.7);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.view-fourth a.info:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.view-fourth:hover img {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1,1.1);

}
.view-fourth:hover .mask {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
.view-fourth:hover h2,
.view-fourth:hover p,
.view-fourth:hover a.info {
    -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    -webkit-filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
    -o-transform: translateY(0px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0px);

}
.view-fourth:hover p {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
.view-fourth:hover a.info {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And you have errors in your HTML, like the `<link`> above the `<head>` and the `</a>` without any matching `<a>`. Run your page through the W3C validator at http://validator.w3.org/ and correct all errors it finds.

Different browsers respond differently to errors, so making it error-free should be the first step in making it multi-browser compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. I programmed it last night, so errors may occur (everywhere) :p. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

IE, even IE9 does not support CSS transitions AFIAK.

Comment: okay, thanks for the quick answer. Do you know of any alternative?

Comment: It will work in IE10. But yes, transitions are future soup; if you need the effect to work in commonly-deployed browsers today you should use scripted animations.

Answer (score 1):

Step one: include a document type declaration at the start of the file, such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you don't, you end up in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_Mode), which greatly increases the differences between IE and other browsers.

Comment: This is true, but, as his code is XHTML, a XHTML doctype declaration would be better as to not confuse the W3C validator.

Comment: Yes, though this would be a valid XHTML5 doctype FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

Your internet explorer uses css 2, but in your code you use the css 3. If you need to use this functionality, the best method is to use a javascript/jquery codding, this will works in internet explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you learn to program in such a way?
You have a very basic website and the CSS that you have is monstrously disproportional.
For your specific website, the CSS should be 10-20 lines of code maximum.
I recommend that you start from scratch and follow this rule.

Comment: Actually, i have never learned how to write proper CSS. I have just started to study web developing a couple of weeks ago, so everything you see is self-learned. Thanks anyway, i will remember that principle. Actually i did have a hinch that it was way too disproportional, but atm i dont have the knowledge to do it the correct way. I am just doing this to get some kind of experience, and also for the fun of it...

Comment: The thing to look at would be combining some of the repeated rules you've got into shared classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your site has issues beyond your messy code. Your background image is entirely too large, taking several seconds for me to load on a new MBP with cable internet.

Your navigation doesn't give your users any idea what your images link to until they mouse over. You'd be better off with a horizontal navigation, using text and smaller thumbnails.

Your Photoshop gallery images are too small. Why do you even have an "About Me" section with nothing about you in it? And black text on a dark gray background?

I don't mean to be super harsh, here. It's better than I was able to produce when I first got into HTML and CSS, but you've got some serious design flaws.